# Apache Kafka integration with tomcat and spring

Tags: spring, http, tomcat, apache-kafka

I am new to kafka, I am thinking of integration kafka message queue with incoming http request and consuming in my web application. here my question is how to capture the incoming request in tomcat to my kafka and in which format should i consume by my spring MVC application. I am not sure if this is the right way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use can make rest API around the http request.

Make Domain object to parse the incomming data from request and send it to Kafka cluster for stream lining other system, which would need live data,

Spring Kafka would work like charm with Spring MVC.

For further reference you can check following link : 
https://www.codenotfound.com/2016/09/spring-kafka-consumer-producer-example.html

Hope it help your thoughts :)